# Problem getting XML properly formatted

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I use classes (autogenerated from a schema) to generate xml documents. It has worked fine, until now, when I need to use inline HTML elements. I've tried several different methods, but as soon as I use the inline HTML, the "<" and ">" gets replaced with %lt; etc.

Example:

```
<meta>
    <name>test</name>
    <value>test <br />new row</value>
</meta>
```

becomes "destroyed" later on when trying to get it as a string for database storage, the value is changed to:

```
    <value>test &lt;br /&gt;new row</value>
```

How is it possible to keep the angle brackets intact?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp) sections for XML (or XML like) content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It did not work for me though, or I'm probably using it wrong. Now I got:

<value>&lt;![CDATA[Hej,&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;En ny test!&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Kalle]]&gt;</value>

Answer (score 2):

The XML write is escaping the reserved characters such as `<`, `>` etc. If you're reading the text back using a Xml reader then your `&lt;` will be correctly read as `<`.